# grouped stacked sales column chart

Tags: charts, excel-2010

I am trying to produce a sales chart using only the native Excel features, I am trying to group sales data by month and category. I want my sale types to stack for a monthly total so that I can compare not only total volume, but also track where that volume is coming from. I have been able to group by month using a pivot chart, but I can't figure out how group my categories and display them as discrete parts of the monthly sum. Here is a mock-up of what I am trying to produce: http://i.imgur.com/BCFfwQJ.png

I'm helpless in VBA and SQL, and my coworkers are even worse than me at it, so I need to do this with just the built-in Excel 2010 features.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the data so the months are in the first column, type labels in the first row, values in columns under the respective type, and keep the top left cell blank (above months and left of types). Add another column with the quota label next to the type labels and the quota values next to the type values. Make a stacked column chart from this data, right click on the quota series (which is another stacked column), choose Change Series Chart Type from the pop=up menu, and choose a line chart type.

Comment: I can do that if I am manually tailoring the data columns for this chart. What I am trying to do is have Excel sum entries by month (your solution would otherwise give me an entry for every single day) and then plot the results as a column which should be stacked by category. I am working with a high volume of data, so manually splitting the date into discrete columns is not feasible. The above illustration is an extremely simplified version which I generated using the same method you described.

Comment: My answer was apparently also oversimplified. Set up the data as I suggested, except with dates (day-month-year dates), not months, in the first column. Then build a pivot table from this data, with dates grouped by month (http://peltiertech.com/grouping-by-date-in-a-pivot-table/). Now follow my instructions for making a chart, using the pivot table as the source data.